# Page dom elemente not rendered Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, primeng

I added Primeng to my application. After I did this no page component is rendered any more. I dont get any error or other advice what I have to do. My html page only shows nothing at the end. I am using Angular and primeng.

```
{
  "name": "angular-wiegmann",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/localize": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.11",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.11",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.22",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^9.3.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.19.1",
    "ng-material-multilevel-menu": "^4.12.2",
    "ng-quill": "^4.5.3",
    "primeicons": "^4.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.1.2",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.11",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

my app.module.ts:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {CreateEmployeeComponent} from './create-employee/create-employee.component';
import {EmployeeDetailsComponent} from './employee-details/employee-details.component';
import {EmployeeListComponent} from './employee-list/employee-list.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {LandingpageComponent} from './landingpage/landingpage.component';
import {NgbCarouselModule, NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {OverviewComponent} from './productoverview/overview.component';
import {MDBBootstrapModule} from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import {NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule} from 'ng-material-multilevel-menu';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MegaMenuModule} from 'primeng';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CreateEmployeeComponent,
    EmployeeDetailsComponent,
    EmployeeListComponent,
    LandingpageComponent,
    OverviewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbCarouselModule,
    NgbModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MegaMenuModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

my app.component.html

```
<p-megaMenu [model]="items"></p-megaMenu>
<div class="">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and my service:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MegaMenuItem} from 'primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular8-springboot-client';
  items: MegaMenuItem[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
      {
        label: 'Categories',
        items: [
          [
            {
              label: 'Shopping',
              items: [
                {
                  label: 'Auto & Motorrad',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Auto & Motorrad'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Bücher',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Bücher'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Büromaterial',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Büromaterial'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Lebensmittel',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Lebensmittel'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Geschenke',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Geschenke'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Gesundheit',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Gesundheit'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Garten & Wohnen',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Garten & Wohnen'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Kunst',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Kunst'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Kleidung',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Kleidung'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Dienstleistungen',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Dienstleistungen'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Spiele',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Spiele'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Sport',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Sport'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Sport',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Sport'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Elektro & Technik',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Elektro & Technik'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Wellness',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Wellness'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Zeitungen & Zeitschriften',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Zeitungen & Zeitschriften'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Sonstiges',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Sonstiges'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Computer',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Computer'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Haustier',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Haustier'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Gutscheine',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Gutscheine'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Schönheitspflege',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Schönheitspflege'
                },
                {
                  label: 'Karriere & Jobs',
                  url: '/overview/Shopping/Karriere & Jobs'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              label: 'Video 2',
              items: [{label: 'Video 2.1'}, {label: 'Video 2.2'}]
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              label: 'Video 3',
              items: [{label: 'Video 3.1'}, {label: 'Video 3.2'}]
            },
            {
              label: 'Video 4',
              items: [{label: 'Video 4.1'}, {label: 'Video 4.2'}]
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Users', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-users',
        items: [
          [
            {
              label: 'User 1',
              items: [{label: 'User 1.1'}, {label: 'User 1.2'}]
            },
            {
              label: 'User 2',
              items: [{label: 'User 2.1'}, {label: 'User 2.2'}]
            },
          ],
          [
            {
              label: 'User 3',
              items: [{label: 'User 3.1'}, {label: 'User 3.2'}]
            },
            {
              label: 'User 4',
              items: [{label: 'User 4.1'}, {label: 'User 4.2'}]
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              label: 'User 5',
              items: [{label: 'User 5.1'}, {label: 'User 5.2'}]
            },
            {
              label: 'User 6',
              items: [{label: 'User 6.1'}, {label: 'User 6.2'}]
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Events', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar',
        items: [
          [
            {
              label: 'Event 1',
              items: [{label: 'Event 1.1'}, {label: 'Event 1.2'}]
            },
            {
              label: 'Event 2',
              items: [{label: 'Event 2.1'}, {label: 'Event 2.2'}]
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              label: 'Event 3',
              items: [{label: 'Event 3.1'}, {label: 'Event 3.2'}]
            },
            {
              label: 'Event 4',
              items: [{label: 'Event 4.1'}, {label: 'Event 4.2'}]
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'Settings', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-cog',
        items: [
          [
            {
              label: 'Setting 1',
              items: [{label: 'Setting 1.1'}, {label: 'Setting 1.2'}]
            },
            {
              label: 'Setting 2',
              items: [{label: 'Setting 2.1'}, {label: 'Setting 2.2'}]
            },
            {
              label: 'Setting 3',
              items: [{label: 'Setting 3.1'}, {label: 'Setting 3.2'}]
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              label: 'Technology 4',
              items: [{label: 'Setting 4.1'}, {label: 'Setting 4.2'}]
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }


}
```

Has anyone the same problem or knows a solution ?

My console is this:

```
+ @angular/cdk@10.0.1
updated 1 package and audited 1504 packages in 14.93s

56 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 317 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

D:\AffiliateShop\wiegmann-angular\angular-wiegmann>ng serve  --o
Compiling primeng/dom : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/api : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/bidi : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/collections : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/inputtext : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/button : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/tooltip : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/observers : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/focustrap : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/utils : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/messages : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/progressbar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/portal : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/accordion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/a11y : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/autocomplete : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/blockui : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/breadcrumb : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/dropdown : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/calendar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/captcha : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/card : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/carousel : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/chart : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/checkbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/chips : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/codehighlighter : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/colorpicker : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/paginator : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/confirmdialog : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/contextmenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/defer : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/dialog : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/dragdrop : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/dynamicdialog : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/dataview : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/editor : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/fieldset : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/fileupload : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/fullcalendar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/galleria : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/gmap : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/inplace : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/inputmask : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/inputnumber : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/inputswitch : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/inputtextarea : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/keyfilter : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/lightbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/listbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/megamenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/menu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/menubar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/message : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/multiselect : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/orderlist : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/organizationchart : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/overlaypanel : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/panel : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/panelmenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/password : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/picklist : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/progressspinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/radiobutton : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/rating : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/scrollpanel : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/selectbutton : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/sidebar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/slidemenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/slider : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/spinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/splitbutton : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/steps : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/tabmenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/tabview : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/terminal : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/tieredmenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/toast : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/togglebutton : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/toolbar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/tree : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/treetable : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/tristatecheckbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/virtualscroller : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/clipboard : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/drag-drop : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/overlay : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/layout : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/text-field : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/accordion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/stepper : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/tree : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng : es2015 as esm2015

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 203 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 150 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.56 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 9.28 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-07-05T10:37:50.747Z - Hash: 42375a7c224d05428a53 - Time: 39866ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.

Date: 2020-07-05T10:47:19.467Z - Hash: 391d2a88fbb0092fc85f
4 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 203 kB [initial] [rendered]
Time: 2715ms
: Compiled successfully.
```

this is my browser error:

```
platform.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Platform cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/platform.js (platform.js:78)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/scrolling.js (scrolling.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../node_modules/primeng/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/primeng-dropdown.js (primeng-dropdown.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../node_modules/primeng/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/primeng-paginator.js (primeng-paginator.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../node_modules/primeng/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/primeng-dataview.js (primeng-dataview.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

Comment: What does the console output? Does your app successfully compile? You said *you don't get any error*, are you talking about browser console or in the compilation?

Comment: yes it does. I added the console output to the post.

Comment: Can you post the browser console's output? Oftentimes, the compilation process completes successfully but, browser console reveals runtime errors and those errors usually prevent the whole page from rendering.

Comment: thanks for the advice with the browser there is an error

Comment: what do I have to do to solve the browser errors

Comment: Your Angular Core version is `9.1.11` and Angular CDK version is `10.x.x`. Can you try downgrading CDK to 9.x?

Comment: thanks it solved my problem